# Single step batch delete in Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, batch-file, rake-task

How to send such a query to database server from Rake task without removing record-by-record in "each" loop?

```
delete from data
where uuid in (
    select uuid
    from data
    group by uuid, raw, recdate
    having count(*)>1
);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ActiveRecord has the `delete_all` method for you. Note that it does not call the destroy callbacks. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete_all

Comment: Is there a rails console function which calls destroy callbacks when deleting parents?

Comment: `.destroy_all` does it but that is not a single-step batch delete the question asked for.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I use small query to iterate over deletes

```rb
while Topic.limit(1000).delete_all > 0 do
  next
end
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).